# css separator line issue

Tags: html, css, border, line

I've been trying to create a separator line, similar to the image bellow, using CSS only. I've seen this in many websites and seems something quite easy to do. What's the best way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i have understood your question, give this a try:

```
<div id="lineWrap">
<span id="center"></span>
<span id="outer"></span>
</div><!--lineWrap-->

div#lineWrap {position:relative; height:3px;}
div#lineWrap span {position:absolute; left:0px; display:block;}
div#lineWrap span#center {top:1px; height:1px; background:#999; width:400px;}
div#lineWrap span#outer {top:0px; height:3px; background:#fd6e6e;width:40px;}
```

Here >>> http://jsfiddle.net/RHf9L/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would be the best way to do it.

```
HTML:

<div class='seperator'>
   <div class='redSep'></div>
   <div class='graySep'> </div>
</div>

CSS:

.seperator{
   width:100%;
   height:20px;
}
.redSep{
   width:30px;
   left:0;
   float:left;
   height:4px;
   background-color: #ff3322;
   z-index:2;
   position:relative;
   margin-right:-30px;
   top:0px;
}
.graySep{
   width:100%;
   top:1px;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
   left:0;
   height:2px;
   background-color:#eee;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jdRXG/1/

Comment: This solution works great too just like the previous one ;)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QUvU7/

You can use the :after psuedoselector to "fake" dom elements without actually adding them like such:

```
.top:after{
    content: "";
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```